# Would it be useful to introduce country name tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Currently, as far as I know, we have only one [question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17837/who-was-the-first-korean-to-compete-in-the-olympics) which has country name tags. I, personally, think that country name tags are efficient and add value to the community: it can attract relatively new users/motivate old ones to answer the questions about the sports in the countries they are familiar with.

It can also help to correctly tag some questions, e.g: we have Spanish [la-liga](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la-liga) tag, but we currently have 4 questions about Spanish Copa del Rey ([1](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17731/would-the-copa-del-rey-change-its-name-for-a-queen), [2](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17700/how-many-yellow-cards-before-player-is-suspended-in-copa-del-rey), [3](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4008/where-will-the-copa-del-rey-final-2014-be-played), [4](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4076/suspension-across-spanish-competitions)) without [copa-del-rey](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copa-del-rey) tag, which can be organized under [spain](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spain) tag.

Similarly, there's a [english-premier-league](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-premier-league) tag, but we don't have tags for [english-fa-cup](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-fa-cup) or [english-league-cup](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-league-cup), which can be gathered under one [england](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/england) tag.

I can think of many scenarios where country name tags may be useful. I also understand that if we give it a go, we should define a universal tag wiki template for country name tags and then use it to write specific tag wikis for each new country name tag.

Please add your thoughts on how country name tags can help you in the sports you are interested in (as I'm mainly dealing with [football](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/football)) or tell us why do you think it is not useful.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see a use for these tags.

To use your example, [english-premier-league](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-premier-league) would stand alone as a tag for suitable questions.  Adding [england](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/england) would be superfluous.  The same applies for the [spain](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spain) tag that you suggest.

If necessary, tags can be extended.  For example [la-liga](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la-liga) could be renamed [spain-la-liga](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spain-la-liga) or a synonym created.  That would help those who don't know that it is a Spanish competition.

But the general practice on SE sites is not to add tags that aren't necessary.  In the sports that I follow, country tags would not help in the slightest.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. We **don't need** those tags. Anywhere it would come up, there's already a tag that tells us the country by default. And grouping all the Spanish or German or Brazilian or Japanese sports together just to follow the country? This is not how realistic sports enthusiasts work - they focus on sport first and country second.

Comment: "Sport first and country second" - I totally agree with that, but it doesn't mean we should eliminate the "second".

Comment: We're not eliminating it, it's not there to begin with. If it was important enough as a second, it would already be coming up naturally, yet nobody has ever bothered to create a country tag in their question. That says everything we need to know about this idea.

Comment: @Nij, that's just not true. From time to time, users are creating country tags. You don't see them because we instantly untag them. Besides that, the very idea of *"we haven't done something previously, let's keep not doing it"* isn't necessarily the best one.

Comment: I have not once ever seen a country tag included on a question where there wasn't a tag already more clearly identifying both the country and the sport at the same time. Removing unnecessary tags is good editing. If these tags are always removed as unnecessary, then *ipso facto* the country tags are not necessary. @gdrt

Comment: @Nij, no, they are being removed as we never established them. You're still referring to the same idea, which I, in my previous comment, told you isn't necessarily the best one.

Comment: You can't remove something that isn't established. Either the tags were there or they weren't. Please make up your mind which one it is. Preferably by pointing to a question where the country tag was wrongly removed.

Comment: Analyzing your previous comment: 1. Philosophical statement. 2. Another philosophical statement. 3. Passive aggressive suggestion to respond to your philosophical statement. 4. The only sentence that has some useful information, to which the answer is: it's hard to find questions with the tags that have been untagged.

Comment: Your "analysis" is nonsense, and only covers the refusal to demonstrate the point with evidence. Argue legitimately or accept the position isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'd like to see it happen,  and not just for less frequented competitions with no own tags. This way we can easily follow all sports from a specific country. Also different countries have different rules that may not be specific to a certain competition, so in such a case as country tag helps as well.

Also I don't like the naming convention of competitions as we have them right now. Chenmunka already pointed out that we could (or should) rename them to include the country the competition is from. But I'd like to see it the other way round and remove the country from them. Everyone asking about the EPL knows where it is.

- [premier-league](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/premier-league)
- [la-liga](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la-liga)
- [bundesliga](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bundesliga) <- this should be a tag not exclusive to German Football. A lot of top level sports leagues are called Bundesliga, including the Austrian Football Bundesliga.
- etc.

For competitions with currently no tag or general questions we can use tagging like this:

- [handball](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handball) [germany](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany)
- [football](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/football) [england](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/england) for example the FA Cup would go here
- [cricket](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cricket) [england](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/england)

  and for competitions with a tag:
- [football](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/football) [premier-league](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/premier-league) [england](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/england)

Now lazy as I am I can use the [england](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/england) and see that one Cricket question, the EPL and FA cup questions and whatever else belongs to England. Or I follow the tag [germany](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany) and answer all Bundesliga (Football, Handball, etc) questions and whatever else there is, because I know more than just Football in Germany.